# Prevent multiple installations of the WiX bundle. It should prevent running while another installation of the same bundle is running

Tags: xml, wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper

right now I have Wix bundle which installs .NET and VC++ as pre-req along with my other MSIs. But the problem is if I run it once, and then run it again while the first one is already running, it doesn't stop the installation. (Multiple instances of the installation are not blocked)
I am using BURN. Candle and Light.
Sorry, I am a newbie, would appreciate the help.
I want it to run only once and possibly display "Another installation is already running" message.
Would appreciate help, stuck at this particular problem for too long.

Comment: are you using standard bootstrapper or custom?

Comment: Standard bootstrapper.

Comment: I know how to do it, but only in custom one. can share if needed

Comment: Any help would be appreciated... Please do share.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As for me you can try two ways how to do it:

1. Custom action:

Just add your msi first in chain and add custom action with check on msi start. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68097883/how-to-add-a-warning-message-if-app-is-open-and-user-want-to-uninstall-it/68119353#68119353) you can find custom action sample. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862794/wix-custom-action-on-startup) you can find how to run it at start. This way is easy and fast.

2. Custom bootstrapper:

This way is little bit long and hard, but it will work too.
First of all you need to create your own custom bootstrapper. [Here's](https://www.wrightfully.com/part-1-of-writing-your-own-net-based-installer-with-wix-overview/) good step-by-step guide to do it.

After you'll have one just add check before Engine run. It will look like this:

```
public class CustomBootstrapperApplication : BootstrapperApplication
{

   /// <summary>
   /// Entry point of managed code
   /// </summary>
   protected override void Run()  
   {
      if (Process.GetProcessesByName("process_name").Length > 0)
      {
         MessageBox.Show("process_name is already running");
         //not sure messagebox will be good idea here according to MVVM, 
         //but I guess you'll find way to solve it or... it will work anyway)))
      }
      //all that engine management stuff
   } 
}
```

Little bit overhead, but as result you'll get your own WPF bootstrapper with UI you want.

Comment: This does look effective. I am sorry, but I am using the BURN method I think. I write the script in an XML file and use Candle and Light with extensions...

Comment: But as least you have msi that you can change? or it's not wix msi? for second option everything will be the same - you'll write xml and will use Candle to burn, but you'll have another project as UI wrapper

Comment: The msi is not a Wix MSI. I have a set of MSI which I directly just bundle. Can I use some conditions or any other things like those in my bundle.wxs? Or any other things like that? Thanks....

Comment: sorry, I don't know are there any conditions and dialogs in bootstrapper. seems like not. you can always add new msi to run that check - it's easiest way